# How to inspect contents of different Docker image layers?

Tags: docker

My current understanding of a Docker image is that it is a collection of individual layers. Each layer only contains deltas that are merged via the union filesystem (which simply mounts all layers on top of each other). When instantiating an image, another (writable) layer is put on top that will then contain all container-specific changes that are persisted between restarts. Please correct me if I am wrong in any of the above.

I would like to inspect the contents of each of the various layers. I am particularly interested in inspecting the top-most layer to see whether my containerized app writes any data that would bloat the container, like a log or so. I am working on macOS, which does not store all the files in `/var/lib/docker/`, but seems to store them in a VM. I read about the `docker-machine` tools that make it easy to connect to the Docker engine via SSH, where one would be able to see and mount all layers. However, this tool seems to be discontinued.

Does anybody have an idea on 1) how to connect to the docker engine to get access to the layers and 2) how to find out what files are contained in a particular layer?

*edit:* It seems to be possible to use `docker diff` to see the file differences between the original image and the running container, which is what I mainly wanted to achieve, but the original questions remain.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400479/find-to-which-container-or-image-a-docker-aufs-diff-folder-belongs-to

Comment: This is a good start and I see the folder `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/..` in various commands (like in `docker inspect ...`), but this folder does not exist in my host FS. Apparently, macOS runs a VM for Docker (in which this path exists). How can I connect to this VM?

Comment: It probably depends on the OS version, but this touches on it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739560/how-to-access-the-vm-created-by-dockers-hyperkit

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can list the layers and their sizes with the `docker history` command. But to inspect the contents of all layers I recommend to use the [dive tool](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive).

Comment: Thanks never heard of that dive tool, it is exactly what I was looking for.